# MongoDB что лучше больше коллекций или документов?

Tags: база-данных, mongodb

Скажем есть 10 миллионов id от "0000001" до "10000000" у них уникальные свойства $name:

1) id можно разбить на 1000 коллекций, получим в каждой коллекции по 10000 документов(id).

2) Или можно засунуть все 10 миллионов документов(id) в одну коллекцию.

На сервер приходит массив из 100 свойств у которых заранее известно к какой из 1000 коллекций они принадлежат.

1. И в первом случае мы 100 раз выбираем одну из 1000 коллекций,
   которую знаем, и выполняем в ней команду (среди 10000 id)

   findOne(array('userID' => $name))
2. а во втором случае 100 раз в одной коллекции выполняем команду
   (среди 10000000id)

   findOne(array('userID' => $name))

Какой способ будет производительнее?

Comment: Каждый документ должен храниться отельно вне зависимости от производительности. К тому же, если вы будете хранить их подколлециями, то, насколько понимаю, не сможете нормально настроить индексирование по атрибутам. Если у вас медленно работает БД, то, возможно, ее надо регулярно выгружать в оптимизированную прослойку, но не трогать саму структуру.